# ubuntu 17.10 - VirtualBox kernel configuration is invalid (4.13.0-37-generic)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 17.10

VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.13.0-37-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

```
       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

5.2.8r121009

I'm facing this issue with virtualbox after a distro upgrade and i've already tried to downgrade the kernel to 4.13.0-16-generic but its not working! Virtualbox is still looking for kernel 4.13.0-37-generic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```